# Django 1.6 OrderedDict retaining state across requests? or cacheing enabled by default?

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.6.0.  I am working on a web app with a client "dashboard".  In the client dashboard there are tabs in the header of the base template.  The tabs are dynamic and change based on the role/permissions of the user viewing the dashboard.

All the views are written using class based views.  All of the dashboard views inherit from a parent mixin view that makes sure the logged in user has permission to view the objects that they requested to view, and that builds the dashboard tabs based on their user role.

```
class ParentMixin(object):
  pages = OrderedDict([
    ('General': { 'link': build_a_link_for_the_logged_in_user()}),
  ])

  def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
     # validate that logged in user has permission to view requested objects
     if user_passes_test(self.request.user):
        self.object = get_users_object_to_view(self.request.user)

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     if self.request.is_superuser and self.object.is_demo:
        self.pages['Superuser'] = {'link': build_link()}
     context = super(parent_get_context_data)
     context['pages'] = self.pages
```

Then in base template that all dashboard views inherit from, the dynamic tabs/links are displayed:

```
            {% for page_name, page_data in pages.items %}
                {% if page_data.is_current %}
                    <a href="{{ page_data.link }}" class="current">
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ page_data.link }}">
                {% endif %}

                    {{ page_name }}
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
```

**My Question:**

This morning, i noticed if I had a requested a demo object, then clicked on a link to view a different objects dashboard, the last objects `Superuser` Link would still show up in the pages dictionary!!!!  I put in debug statements in the view.  The view would recognize that I was a superuser and the `object.is_demo` was False.  So the conditionaly would not add the `Superuser` link to the `self.pages`.  **But the `Superuser` link was still in `self.pages` and it had the Link from the last object I viewed.**  This is the only place that `self.pages['Superuser']` was being set.

**Does anyone know how this data could persist between requests? Or could see something wrong with my approach??**
I fixed the bug this morning by removing the `Superuser` from `self.pages` before doing the conditional check to see if a superuser was making the request and the object was a demo:

```
if 'Superuser' in self.pages:
  del(self.pages['Superuser'])
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing exactly what you tell it. You've set `pages` to be a class attribute of ParentMixin, which means it will also be a class attribute of any view class you mix it in to. Class attributes are shared across all instances of the class within a process, and since a process lasts across many requests, the data will persist across those requests.

You should always set attributes on `self`, which means doing it inside a method, in this case probably inside `get_context_data`. Django goes to some lengths to ensure that instance data is not shared in class-based views, but this does not apply to class-level data.