# Mixin to return a random object on each page load

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a mixin that dynamically generates a random Amazon Affiliates advertisement. I'm not really sure if this is the best way of going about things (for example, would it be better to define a method in the model itself that returns a random item?)...but here's where I am.

I have two apps: `events` and `advertisements`. My mixin in the `advertisements.views` looks something like:

```
class AmazonAdvertisingMixin(object):

    config = {
        # Amazon Config
    }
    api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)

    # Get all ads from the database
    ads = Advertisement.objects.filter(network__exact='Amazon')

    if len(ads) > 0:
        ad = random.choice(ads)

        # Get the ASIN from a random ad
        asin = ad.ASIN

        result = api.item_lookup(asin, ResponseGroup='Images, Small')

        advertisement = {
            'product_url': result.Items.Item['DetailPageURL']
        }

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(AmazonAdvertisingMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['advertisement'] = self.advertisement
            return context
```

Then in my `events.views`, I have a `FormView` that looks like the following:

```
class ContactFormView(AmazonAdvertisingMixin, FormView):

    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "contact.html"

    # etc, etc...
```

This works GREAT for displaying an ad on the contact page. The only problem is...when I refresh the page, the ad is always the same. It's almost as if the mixin is only running once. Is there a way to have it re-run each time the page is loaded, so that I can grab a new `asin`?

I'm also open to other suggestions for achieving the end goal: select a random `advertisement` from the database, on each page load. Thoughts?

Comment: Note that you're querying the database for the entire queryset. You can use `ad = Advertisement.objects.filter(network__exact='Amazon').order_by('?')[0]` instead, or alternatively, use `ads.exists()` instead of `len(ads) > 0`.  This will save a lot of overhead if you have a large number of database entries.

Comment: @knbk I thought `.order_by('?')` was something to be avoided because it's an "expensive" query...No? They say it is [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by). Maybe it doesn't apply to PostgreSQL?

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have recommended that. I always thought it was just a bit slow, but apparently queries can take up to several minutes. However, you will still face the same performance problem if you try to get _all_ the records of a database with 10 million rows (which `len(ads)` does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the ad code IS only running once, on process startup.  The models are not reloaded for every page request, but are initialized one time,

If you put your ad logic in `get_context_data` it should load a random ad on each request, as `get_context_data` is called per request

from a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993065/django-1-6-ordereddict-retaining-state-across-requests-or-cacheing-enabled-by-d) question i asked:

> Class attributes are shared across all instances of the class within a
>   process, and since a process lasts across many requests, the data will
>   persist across those requests.

Comment: Bingo, that did it! Can't believe I didn't consider nesting it all under `get_context_data()`...Doh! Thanks a bunch.