# Keeping state and sharing common processing between django requests

Tags: django, view, python-requests, state, shared

I am building a simple django application that fetches data from a service, processes the data, stores into the database, and serves pages based on the processed data. Data in database is read-only and shown on a static page.

The initial fetch from external service will take a few minutes to populate the database. My current plan is to do the initial long fetch from service on the first page request, with the view for the request setting a flag 'fetch-in-progress' so that further requests don't start another needless fetch.

I am assuming django does process multiple requests concurrently - I just read up a bit and it seems to depend on the wsgi configuration. But I am assuming two requests will get handled by django concurrently and that in my case it will result in two fetches to the service which I want to avoid.

What would be the best place to store the flag? Options that I have read about:

1. In the database as a separate table for just the flag ([Shared object between requests in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927589/shared-object-between-requests-in-django))
2. As a class attribute of the View class that does the fetch from service ([Django 1.6 OrderedDict retaining state across requests? or cacheing enabled by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993065/django-1-6-ordereddict-retaining-state-across-requests-or-cacheing-enabled-by-d))
3. Django session - guess I can't use this as a request from another browser would be via a separate session which would result in needless fetch.
4. Low level cache API (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) - store flag in cache - the documentation says "Repeated requests for the same alias in the same thread will return the same object." - I am not sure if the same thread is used by default in django to serve requests
5. Django middleware - maybe do the initial lengthy fetch at startup?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a persistent central store, so even if you have more than one server with a load balancer, all will access the same flag. If you set attributes to classes at runtime, one server will see the flag, but if the node balancer sends the next request to another server - it will not.

The specific solution is based on the size of the data, frequency of updates, expected traffic, etc, Generally fetching a single flag from the DB is fast, so you should consider if it's worth for you to install and manage a central cache. If you do use central cache, file based cache is easy, then it becomes more complicated. Maybe DB will do? 
You can make it even faster:

1. The flag table with few indexed integer columns, so each DB page covers a lot of index rows
2. Query the DB with direct SQL, just to get the flag with MySQLDB, and save the overhead of django objects and models
3. Use a separate DB from all others django tables.